# Chained Web API services not communicating properly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a new ASP.NET 4 Web API service suite, divided among several individual web applications.  One of the Web API services (the "mediator") handles requests and passes them on to the other services, and passes back their responses (using JSON).  Sometimes it takes the response and merges it with that of one or more other services, sending back the merged result to the client.  I have one such service where, in staging, it works perfectly.  In Production, not so much.  In this case the mediator takes the client request, passes it to one other service, and should just be passing the response right back to the client.  If I call the second service directly, I do not have any issues with the test request.  But if I call it through the mediator it bombs out with the exception:

`"The wait operation timed out", "ExceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"`

It doesn't seem to matter what the size of the response will be - 60 bytes, or 60 KB.  The other part of it is some requests are successful.  The difference only seems to be what is IN the Request. If I send the request with the main parameter set to one value, it comes back fine.  If I set it to another value it times out.  It does this consistently but only for the mediator service.  The secondary service returns the correct result sets for each parameter value.  The result set for the parameter value that triggers the timeout is smaller than the one that succeeds.

So I don't really get it.  Is there something that happens in the HttpClient class, for example, or in some other ASP.NET library that may be tripping this up with validation on characters I'm not aware of?  I'm not even sure how to test to make sure the response is "good" because the one service works with the same data that apparently chokes the mediator service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding an index to the production database table in question.  We are still unsure as to "Why?" but it turns out the query for the particular column name was taking 4 times longer in production than in staging, with a very-closely-similar set of data in the table.